# I use resttemplate to test my web service but when I run the test I have an error connection to the application

Tags: spring, resttemplate

I use resttemplate to test my web service knowing that I use h2 as database but when I run the test I have an application connection error
error:
org.springframework.we.client.RessourceAccessException: I/O error on get request for "http://localhost: 8082 / parcours":Connect to localhost:8082
I do not know how to start spring boot automatically and it points to my application file that points to h2 database and not the other database

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfig
{
    @Bean
public TestRestTemplate myRestTemplate()
{
return new TestRestTemplate();
}

}



@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(location ={"file:src/ressources/applicationContext.xml"},classes = TestConfig.class)
@RestClienTest(value={ParcoursRessource.class})
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
public class TestParcoursRessource 
{

@Autowired
    private RestTemplate myRestTemplate;

@Test
public void listerParcours()
{
 ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = myRestTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:8082/parcours",String.class);
Assert.assertEquals(OK.getStatusCode(),responseEntity.getStatusCodeValue())
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try with RestAssured.

DOC: https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/GettingStarted

**Example configuration**

Abstract class EndpointTest. ContextConfiguration pointing to your app database config file. This will look for your datasource properties in application.yml in test package, so you can points h2 just for tests:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {YourAppConfig.class})
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public abstract class EndpointTest {

    // App port
    @Value("${local.server.port}") int port;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        RestAssured.port = port;
    }
}
```

Example test method:

```
public class ExampleEndpointTest extends EndpointTest {
    @Test
    public void deleteMultiple(){

        given()
             .pathParam("id","a")
        .when()
             .delete("/example/query/{id}")
        .then()
             .statusCode(HttpStatus.SC_NO_CONTENT);
    }
}
```

Comment: please
what dependency I have to use because in the documentation there are several dependencies?and how can i retrieve the status code from the webservice response.?

Comment: where is it the webservice calls ?

Comment: @anoirEl in my case i use these:         
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    .then().statusCode(...) is returning true if status code is matching.

Also you can do this:
    Response response = given()(...).extract().response();
    assertEquals(response.getStatusCode(), 200)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample one using mockmvc for get and post services, mockmvc available with the spring starter test dependency itself

```
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.delete;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.LocalServerPort;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithMockUser;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;




@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class AppTest {


    @LocalServerPort
    int randomServerPort;


    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;




    private MockMvc mvc;


    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders
          .webAppContextSetup(context)
         // .apply(springSecurity())
          .build();
    }



    @Test
    @WithMockUser("spring")
    public void testGetPage() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(get(<url>).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
           .andExpect(status().is(200));
    }



    @Test
    @WithMockUser("spring")
    public void testRolePost() throws Exception {
        Role role = new Role();

        role.setRoleName("Test Role");
        role.setRead(true);
        role.setWrite(false);
         ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, false);
            ObjectWriter ow = mapper.writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
            String requestJson=ow.writeValueAsString(role );
        mvc.perform(post("/addrole").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) .content(requestJson))
           .andExpect(status().is(200));

    }

}
```

Comment: what context will I inject when calling @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context; ?? knowing that I want the tests start on another applicationContext file that contains a url for database H2

Comment: when I tried what you showed me I had this error: Error creating bean with name 'AppTest' unsatisfied dependency expressed trough field 'context'

Comment: Try modifying the Test config class of yours :   `@Configuration  
@EnableWebMvc  
@ComponentScan( basePackages = { "...." } )  
@EnableTransactionManagement  
@ImportResource( "classpath:applicationContext.xml" )  
public class TestConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {`